# Is there any way to avoid the default height of texts in html?

Tags: html, css, html-table

There seems to be a default height for each and every texts in html. Say for ex. h3 element. When we block the h3 element in firebug, we can see extra space above and below that text. Obviously this can't avoided using reset.css. I tried line-height property also. It doesn't work. Any alternatives?

Here is the code:

```
   <html>
        <head></head>
           <body>
             <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td><h3>Some text goes here</h3></td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Now h3 will have a default height set for it (Not mentioning about any Margins are Paddings). Apart from margin/padding there will be a default height for each and every element. Any solution for this?

Comment: Please formulate the question in terms of sample HTML and CSS code, description of expected rendering, and description of actual rendering, including exact formulation of the difference and the browser(s) used for testing. Without such clarifications, this is “not a real question”.

Comment: Hi Jukka K. Korpela. This dont needs a code I suppose. I need to place a screenshot instead. Since I do not have 10 reputation, I'm unable to do that.

Comment: A screenshot as such would be useless. No code, no real question.

Comment: My guess: It `margin` (or less likely `padding`). Show some code.

Comment: @ Jukka K. Korpela, find my code above.

Answer (score 0):

yes every block elements having their own padding and margin, it can vary from browser to browser. To avoid this use

```
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

it will avoid default padding and margin of all block elements.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to default user-agent-styles from your browser. Applying zero for padding, margin may help you to overcome this.

```
h3 {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
}
```

or you can apply a wild call using,

```
* {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
}
```

Comment: @Sonasish Roy and Prasanth K C....The margins and paddings have been set to 0. Apart from the margin and padding, there is a minute difference in height for all the texts.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are talking about when padding and margin have already been set to 0? You can set a line-height of less that 1 (e.g. `line-height: 0.8`) but I find that a little dangerous. If the space above and below text bothers you, you can always employ negative margins on the element to pull it close to its neighbors.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ralph! Is there any other way to avoid negative margin? Because across all the html pages, say nearly 100 pages, I have this common issue! :(

Comment: But that shouldn't be an issue, as you can update all those pages in one hit in your single style sheet. Could you be more specific? Did you try the line-height suggestion above?

Comment: Yes. I did. I tried the line-height with the negative margin, which made that element to be pushed a little upwards inside that td.

Comment: Just use one or the other. See what effect line-height has on its own. If you don't like that, try using the negative margin instead. I generally find that negative margins are the way to go. If you only want the negative margin after, say, a `table` element, you can do `table + h3 {margin-top: -3px;}` etc.